# Form .keyup(function() jQuery Instant Search

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm attempting to display instant search results from a form located on my page. But I'm not getting any results from the query. I'm not sure if this is because the code as I have written is not calling the form correctly, or if using onblur / onfocus values in the form changes the way the jQuery should be written. As you will see php addresses the onblue / onfocus values to ensure the default text is not included in the query. Any ideas?

[html]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/BookSearch.js"></script>
<form action="php/DisplayBooks.php" method="POST" class="searchbooks">
<table width="620" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="114" align="right">By Course :</td>
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="Subject" value="Subject..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Subject...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Subject...') {this.value = ''; }" /></td>
<td width="348"><input type="text" id="Course" value="Number..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Number...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Number...') {this.value = ''; }" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">By Title :</td>
<td><input type="text" id="Title" value="Book Title..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Book Title...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Book Title...') {this.value = ''; }" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="Edition" value="Edition..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'Edition...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Edition...') {this.value = ''; }" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">By ISBN :</td>
<td><input type="text" id="ISBN" value="ISBN..." onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'ISBN...'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'ISBN...') {this.value = ''; }" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" class="sub-button" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="BookSearch_results"></div>
```

[jQuery]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.searchbooks').keyup(function() {
    var subject_term = $('#Subject').val();
    var course_term = $('#Course').val();
    var title_term = $('#Title').val();
    var edition_term = $('#Edition').val();
    var isbn_term = $('#ISBN').val();
    $.post('php/Display.php', { subject_term: subject_term, course_term: course_term, title_term: title_term, edition_term: edition_term, isbn_term: isbn_term }, function(data) { 
    $('#BookSearch_results').html(data);
    });
});
});
```

[php]

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subject_term'], $_POST['course_term'], $_POST['title_term'], $_POST['edition_term'], $_POST['isbn_term'])){

require 'Connect.php';

$subject_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['subject_term']));
$course_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['course_term']));
$title_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['title_term']));
$edition_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['edition_term']));
$isbn_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['isbn_term']));

if ($subject_term == 'Subject...'){
$subject = '';
} else {$subject = "`Subject` LIKE '%$subject_term%' AND";}
if ($course_term == 'Number...'){
$course = '';
} else {$course = "`Course` LIKE '%$course_term%' AND";}
if ($title_term == 'Book Title...'){
$title = '';
} else {$title = "`Title` LIKE '%$title_term%' AND";}
if ($edition_term == 'Edition...'){
$edition = '';
} else {$edition = "`Edition` LIKE '%$edition_term%' AND";}
if ($isbn_term == 'ISBN...'){
$isbn = '';
} else {$isbn = "`ISBN` LIKE '%$isbn_term%' AND";}

$wc = "`ID`>='1'";

    $search = mysql_query("SELECT `Member`, `Subject`, `Course`, `Title`, `Edition`, `ISBN`, `Image`, `Condition`, `Price`, `Comments` FROM `Books` WHERE $subject $course $title $edition $isbn $wc");
    $result_count = mysql_num_rows ($search);
    $suffix = ($result_count !=1) ? 's' : '';
    echo 'Your search for <strong>', $subject,'</strong> returned <strong>', $result_count,'</strong> result', $suffix;

    while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)){
    echo '<div class="book-post"><div class="book-title"><h4>', $results_row['Title'],'.',$results_row['Edition'],'Edition</h4></div><div class="book-content"><span class="pullquote_left"><img src="', $results_row['Image'],'" width="100" height="100"/></span><span class="pullquote_right"><strong>Posted By:</strong><br/>', $results_row['Member'],'<br/><strong>Price:<br/></strong><em>$', $results_row['Price'],'</em><strong><br/>Condition:<br/></strong><em>', $results_row['Condition'],'Like New</em></span><strong>ISBN :</strong>', $results_row['ISBN'],'<br/><strong>Comments: </strong>', $results_row['Comments'],'.</div></div>';    
    }
}else{
echo '<h3>Please log in to view textbook listings</h3>';
}
?>
```

Thank you for your time,

Anthony

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you might want to look into a HTML5 placeholder shim.  It would remove a huge amount of complexity from your code (all the onblur/onfocus and the testing for placeholder values in the php).

Comment: Are you really sure this is what you want to do? If you get this code to work correctly an AJAX request will be fired for every keystroke and unless grandma is typing I am certain you will have a lot of requests that will go stale. Every time a key is pressed in a field you may want to check and make sure there isn't an ongoing request. If there is, for the benefit of your servers load you might want to cancel that request before sending another.

Comment: That's a very good point. After/If I can get this current code to work I'll look into implementing something along those lines. Perhaps adding a second delay before sending request?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer... but to debug this kind of issues, please use firebug plugin. You will be able to see and inspect the request going to the server and the variables getting sent. Also put break points in your firebug script tab to see if you are reading the right values in the js side. You will be able to solve the problem in a jiffy :)

[Get Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Comment: If "this is probably not the answer" then you should add a comment instead of adding an answer. Comments for the question can be found at the bottom of the question right below the asking poster's badge.

Comment: Sorry, but i couldn't find and "add comment" option under the question... just realized that i need 50 rep to get that option enabled!

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this problem for a few hours. And I'm using chrome to debug, but I still haven't been able to come up with the answer on my own. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: since you are not getting any JS errors & you say you are not getting any results from the query, its probably a server side issue. What exactly the serve returns? Can you echo the SQL query string and see if its as expected?

Comment: I have a default response that doesnt seach SQL for users that are not logged in. And even that is not being responded. So it has to be an error with my jQuery.